# Asking advice on EEG classification using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a dataset on EEG, with this shape:

```
(11,1158, 200)
```

Where

```
11 is the number of EEG channel
1158 is the number of each task
200 is the time interval of each task
```

for example, if you plot a task, you'll get (Note that the data is normalized):

[image]

This task represents a task with a class. (for example seeing a picture from class 2, and total number of classes in my dataset is 5).

Now I converted my array to this shape:

```
(1158, 200, 11)
```

So that the model could differentiate each task. this is the model that I used:

```
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=64, activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 11)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_valid,y_valid), epochs=50, batch_size=16)
```

I tried many different hyper-parameters, but all my results are somewhat like this:

```
Epoch 50/50
58/58 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.1281 - accuracy: 0.9946 - val_loss: 2.7850 - val_accuracy: 0.1897
```

The training accuracy is high, but validation accuracy is between 20% to 25% (100/5 = 20 where 5 is the number of classes); Which basically means the model predicts something random. Is my approach wrong? If so, how should I solve this problem?

Comment: You should specify the number of samples used in your training.

Answer (score 0):

As your data is essentially a time-series classification problem my instinct is to start with something LSTM based.

Sadly my second insight is related to data size.  Your feature space is 200x11=2200 and sample size is 1158.  I tend think of using deep learning if sample size >5 * feature size but really think that DL starts to shine around 10 times ratio.  If gathering more data is not a realistic possibility then you will need to look at other solutions to having a high variance problem (model is too complex for the level of data available).

Third I can comment that your data shape looks right to me assuming you normalized and shaped your validation set equivalently to your training set then that is likely not an issue.

Edit: I just noticed that the final epoch of training shows 58/58 for the samples trained.  This value denotes the number of samples in the training set.  Is this what you were expecting?  I would of expected the number of samples to be say 70% of your total set EG 810/810.
If your unsure of what I'm asking please post the size of y_train and y_valid.  This may help myself and others verify the training process.

Comment: The batch size is 16 so 58 seems correct (58 batchs of 16 series each means each train epoch is 80% of 1158 sequences)?